# How can I launch postgres server headless (without terminal) on Windows?

Tags: postgresql

Using Postgres 9.5 and the libpqxx c++ bindings, I want to launch a copy of postgres that is not installed on the users machine, but is instead packaged up in my application directory. 
Currently, I am using pg_ctl.exe to start and stop the server, however when we do this, pg_ctl.exe seems to launch postgres.exe in a new terminal window.
I want it to launch postgres.exe in a headless state, but can't work out how.

I have tried enabling/disabling the logging collector, setting the logging method to a csv file (instead of stdout/stderr), and a couple of other logging related things, but I don't think the issue is the logging.

I have also tried running postgres.exe manually (without pg_ctl) and can get that to run headless by spawning it as a background process and redirecting the logs, but I would prefer to use the "pg_ctl start" api for the "wait for startup" (-w), and "timeout" (-t) options that it provides.

Comment: I could only do that with a VBscript. With a batch file, I could never get rid of the console window

Comment: When using a VBscript, were you running pg_ctl.exe or postgres.exe directly?

Comment: I am using `pg_ctl` from within the VBscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my use case, I was able to resolve the issue by running pg_ctl.exe using 
[CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), and providing the dwCreationFlags [CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | CREATE_NO_WINDOW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags).
I was originally using CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | DETACHED_PROCESS, but DETACHED_PROCESS still allowed a postgres terminal to appear. This is because DETACHED_PROCESS will spawn the pg_ctl without a console, but any process that inherits stdin/stdout from pg_ctl will try to use it's console, and since there isn't one, one will be spawned. CREATE_NO_WINDOW however will launch the process with a conhost.exe, however the console will have no window. When the executables spawned by pg_ctl try to write to the terminal, they will successfully write to the console created by the conhost.exe which has no window.

I am now able to run pg_ctl from code with no console appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you won't be able to do that with `pg_ctl`.

It is perfectly fine to start PostgreSQL directly through the server executable `postgres.exe`. Alternatively, you can use `pg_ctl register` to create a service and start the service.

Comment: It looks like when I launch directly through postgres.exe, every connection that is spawned will create a new postgres.exe terminal for the new executable. When I launched using pg_ctl.exe, this was not the case, I just had the one the one terminal.
Do you know how to prevent these additional terminals from spawning?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying, but why not use a service then? I thought you had said using `postgres.exe` worked fine for you.

Comment: When I wrote that original comment, I had only just run postgres.exe and got it to run without spawning a new terminal. When I started trying to connect to it, the process forks for every connection, and each new process does launch a new terminal.

We don't want to use a service because we want to isolate postgres databases between windows user accounts. This is somewhat contrary to the standard use case of Postgres I know. Postgres may also not be the best choice of database for our use case, but if we can use it, we can get a lot of stuff for free.